# Very strange behaviour when trying to replicate a table using a Listview and GridLayout

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to replicate a table using a ListView.  Displaying the table's cell content works fine but when I add another GridLayout wrapped in a StackLayout above the Listview the Listview doesn't get displayed at all...  Any idea why this might be happening?  I tried as well to add the table headers to the ListView using nsTemplateKey but still get the same issue where the headers show but no table body content.  When I remove the top GridLayout containing the headers the Listview's content displays perfectly as it should for some reason...

```
my code:

//headers               
<StackLayout class="m-b-10">
<GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *, *" *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0 && !product">
<Label row="0" col="0" text="Name"></Label>
<Label row="0" col="1" text="Qty"></Label>
<Label row="0" col="2" text="Action"></Label>
</GridLayout>
</StackLayout>


//listview containing the table body
<StackLayout *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0 && !product">            
<ListView [items]="stockTakeDetailList">                        
<template let-captureItem="item" let-i="index">
<GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *, *">
<Label row="0" col="0" class="list-group-item" textWrap="true" [text]="captureItem.ProductDetail_Name"></Label>
<Label row="0" col="1" class="list-group-item" [text]="captureItem.Qty"></Label>
<Label row="0" col="2" class="list-group-item font-awesome" text="&#xf1f8;" (tap)="removeCaptureItem(i)"></Label>
</GridLayout>
</template>
</ListView>         
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating all of the code within a StackLayout:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="m-b-10">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *, *" *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0 && !product">
            <Label row="0" col="0" text="Name"></Label>
            <Label row="0" col="1" text="Qty"></Label>
            <Label row="0" col="2" text="Action"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0 && !product">            
        <ListView [items]="stockTakeDetailList">                        
            <template let-captureItem="item" let-i="index">
                <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *, *">
                    <Label row="0" col="0" class="list-group-item" textWrap="true" [text]="captureItem.ProductDetail_Name"></Label>
                    <Label row="0" col="1" class="list-group-item" [text]="captureItem.Qty"></Label>
                    <Label row="0" col="2" class="list-group-item font-awesome" text="&#xf1f8;" (tap)="removeCaptureItem(i)"></Label>
                </GridLayout>
            </template>
        </ListView>         
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Maybe try without the extra stack layouts:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="m-b-10">
        <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *, *" *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0 && !product">
            <Label row="0" col="0" text="Name"></Label>
            <Label row="0" col="1" text="Qty"></Label>
            <Label row="0" col="2" text="Action"></Label>
        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <ListView [items]="stockTakeDetailList" *ngIf="stockTakeDetailList.length > 0 && !product">                        
        <template let-captureItem="item" let-i="index">
            <GridLayout rows="*" columns="*, *, *">
                <Label row="0" col="0" class="list-group-item" textWrap="true" [text]="captureItem.ProductDetail_Name"></Label>
                <Label row="0" col="1" class="list-group-item" [text]="captureItem.Qty"></Label>
                <Label row="0" col="2" class="list-group-item font-awesome" text="&#xf1f8;" (tap)="removeCaptureItem(i)"></Label>
            </GridLayout>
        </template>
     </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: No still only the headers get displayed...  I also tried without any StackLayouts but still only the headers get displayed...  Driving me crazy, I just don't understand why/what's going on here...  I gues a temporary solution is to just add/replicate those 3 labels in every row of the ListView...